# Howto run soap web service on jetty?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jetty, jax-ws

i am struggeling to have a soap webservice run on my embedded jetty server.

I followed this german tutorial (which ofc didnt work):
http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/jee-jax-ws.htm#Deployment-im-Webserver

Relevant code pieces:

```
Endpoint ep = Endpoint.publish( url, new BuecherServiceImpl() );
int anzahlBuecherResult = TestWsClient.test( "WsMitEndpointIntegrTest", url, 4000000000L, anzahlBuecher, true );


public static int test( String testName, String url, long startIsbn, int anzahlBuecher, boolean trace ) throws Exception
{
  BuecherServiceIntf buecherService;
  if( url.equalsIgnoreCase( "direkt" ) ) {
     buecherService = new BuecherServiceImpl();
  } else {
     System.out.println( testName + ": " + url );
     Service service = null;
     int timeoutSekunden = 20;
     while( service == null ) {
        try {
           //here the Exception occurs, maybe because of a wrong qname
           service = Service.create(
                 new URL( url + "?wsdl" ),
                 new QName( "http://soap.apachecxf/" , "BuecherServiceImplService" ) );
        } catch( WebServiceException ex ) {
           if( timeoutSekunden-- <= 0 ) throw ex;
           try { Thread.sleep( 1000 ); } catch( InterruptedException e ) {/*ok*/}
        }
     }
     buecherService = service.getPort( BuecherServiceIntf.class );
  }
```

sun-jaxws.xml

```
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">

<endpoint name="BuecherService" implementation="soap.apachecxf.BuecherServiceImpl" url-pattern="/ws/BuecherService" />

</endpoints>
```

Can somebody provide me with some help here?

Comment: Late but maybe this can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418158/embedded-jetty-adding-context-after-starting-jetty-server/38530242#38530242] (see second code listing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can run soap web service with embedded jetty by override default HttpServerProvider property. Make sure that you have added [jetty-http-spi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http-spi) jar file on classpath

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider", "org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider");
```

org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider is an [implementation of Java HTTP Server SPI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/index.html) provided by [Jetty](https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.0.RC5/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/http/spi/JettyHttpServerProvider.html)

You can verify if the server running is jetty by looking at Server response header.
This code worked for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ContentWsImplement contentImplement = new ContentWsImplement();
    System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider", "org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider");
    Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8000/services/getcontent", contentImplement);
}
```